# "No such module found" while using CocoaPods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods

I am developing an app using the CocoaPods GoogleAPIClient and GTMOAuth2.

I successfully installed the CocoaPods to my project.

If I clean the project it shows an error: "No such module found" and the frameworks change to the color red.

Comment: You may be getting down voted partly because your question is hard to read.

Comment: when i build my project everything works fine if i clean my project means frameworks are getting error as no such modules found.my frameworks which is in project changes to red

Comment: I have edited your question to improve its clarity

Comment: I think it will also help if you copy the detailed error into your question

Comment: you have any ideas about this one @brad thomas

Answer (score 0):

Run the project without import pod first, then run it again and this time with import pod.
Also try cmd+shift+K

If still doesn't, manually dragg googleapiclient sourcefile to your project and it should work 100% this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had this same problem with my project. I just cleaned the project and Command+B (build the project). This worked fine for me.